# How to pass primary key of one model into a form field of another model?

Tags: django

I have two models, Task and TaskNote, and I am trying to get the current Task's primary key entered as an initial value in the TaskNoteForm when the form is called from the current Task's view.

On the task detail view there is a link to a form where the user can write a note that will appear on the detail view. I would like the form to have the Task instance primary key set as a foreign key in TaskNote (for example, as model attribute "subject").

My solution was to get the URL using a 'HTTP_REFERER' request and parse the pk from the URL, then pass the pk into context data in the view, and finally enter it as a value in template. For example:

```
# Models

class Task(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True)
    ...
class TaskNote (models.Model):
    ...
    subject = models.ForeignKey(
        Task,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

# view

def get_url_pk(self):
    url = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    t = url.split('/')
    pk = int(t[-1])
    return pk

class TaskNotesCreate(CreateView):
    template_name='tasknotes_new.html'
    form_class = TaskNoteForm
    model = TaskNote

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TaskNotesCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['pk'] = get_url_pk(self)
        return context

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        obj = self.object
        return reverse('task_view', kwargs={'pk': obj.subject_id})

# template
...
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleInput" class="required">
          <input type="hidden"  name="subject" value="{{ pk }}">
      </div>
```

This works fine, however...

1. I have learned that HTTP_REFERER is not the preferred method as it can be disabled in some browsers. I can't seem to find the what the preferred method is in the docs, so if anyone could help me on that, that would be great.  But also, before I spend a lot to time hacking something else together, I am wondering...
2. Is there a better, more acceptable way to pass the pk to the form???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing the template, you can do it the following way:

1. Update your `TaskNoteForm` so it has hidden input field for the value you want to pass along (this is a normal form field with `widget=HiddenInput()`).
2. On the view, overwrite `get_initial` to pass the object's value as the pk. This should look like

```
     def get_initial():
            initial = super().get_initial()
            initial.update(
                {"pk": self.object.pk}
            )
            return initial
```